# Does guice allow injectMembers into a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, guice, inject

My problem is here; I don't know if i can do that with guice:

```
public class Foo {
 private final Bar bar;

 @Inject
 public Foo(Injector injector) {
  this.bar = new Bar();
  injector.injectMembers(bar);
 }
}
```

*bar will be injected correctly or not ? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: The problem is I cant try it, i'm building currently a big DSL and i need the answer quickly !

Comment: I just want to know if this code works or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should work. It's OK for the process of constructing one instance to cause other injections to occur (in fact, this is the way dependency injection works normally).

A probably better alternative for the same effect would be:

```
@Inject Foo(Provider<Bar> barProvider) {
  this.bar = barProvider.get();
}
```

Since this will cause Guice to construct the `Bar` instance and inject its fields.

As an aside, this example demonstrates some bad practices:

- It's bad form to make `@Inject` constructors `public`. The whole point of dependency injection is to make it so that clients of your class don't need to know about your class's dependencies. That's subverted if they ever construct the class directly. If you really want a "default" constructor, just provide a non-`@Inject` constructor or a factory method (either on the class or elsewhere in the package).
- `injectMembers` is usually a best avoided if possible. Wherever possible, prefer constructor injection. Among other things, this is necessary if you're going to be sharing instances across threads, since `injectMembers` may not guarantee safe publication. Like any post-constructor initialization step, it also makes class invariants harder to reason about.
- As you've probably inferred, injecting the `Injector` is a code smell. Outside of really heavy metaprogramming or framework code, it should almost never be necessary. Like reflection, it can be a great way to build "magic" functionality, but also like reflection, it can also cause extremely weird runtime errors if you do it wrong.

Comment: Thank you. But my example is not really my situation. I really need to inject a field which'sn't able to be created by a provider.

Comment: @Romain-p: why can't you use a `Provider` here? Can you provide more code to demonstrate what's going on? There may be other techniques (e.g. possibly you could extend the Guice binding DSL with your own methods for building bindings) that would make this approach less fragile.

Comment: I can show you the code if you have skype  (by screen share).

Comment: @Romain-p: I don't really want to see your code, just a sketch of why you need to do it this way. Could you put an example (suitably anonymized) in a gist or pastebin? (Or better yet, an anonymized/redacted version on codereview.stackexchange.com?) It's possible that you really do need field injection, but it seems likely that there's a better way.

Comment: I need to inject getAction() (Command): https://gist.github.com/Romain-P/8fcaeda4fa075ff8ab21

Comment: +1, though if `Provider<Bar>` provides exactly one instance within the constructor, just inject `Bar` instead. Great answer!